# how to move object in a circle around point?

Tags: physics, python, pygame

There are two controllable objects orbiting around a centre block. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to stick them so they can only move around the block (left/a sends them clockwise, right/a sends them anti-clockwise) and can only get them to move like normal sprites not on a set path.

I haven't got any code to show yet, but I could really appreciate either some advice, or preferably some examples.

Comment: I recently asked a similar question, you can find it [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197418/could-you-explain-how-this-gameobject-rotating-around-another-gameobject-works).

Answer (score 0):

consider constant velocity for a simplier explaination.

in a linear movement you would calculate each frame's delta position depending on your velocity and adjust your object location adding the result.

ds = v * dt

in a circular movement things are quite the same but you have to calculate delta angle based on your angular velocity.

dϕ = ω * dt

compute your new position with

p = (x = cosϕ * r, y= sinϕ * r)

given r the distance of your object from the center of the circle