# Could you explain how this GameObject rotating around another GameObject works?

Tags: mathematics, trigonometry

I'm just learning Unity and I follow a tutorial for a simple game which I want to build up from.

I'm already mostly done with the course and at the end a "boss enemy" gets implemented.

Its special ability is, that it has some other GameObject (a fireball) floating around itself.

It is all done in a single line of code in the update method which I don't quite understand yet, so any explanation would be great.

Here is the code:

```
private void Update()
{
    fireball.position = transform.position + 
        new Vector3(
            -Mathf.Cos(Time.time * fireballSpeed) * distance, 
            Mathf.Sin(Time.time * fireballSpeed) * distance, 
            0);
}
```

- `fireball` is the transform of the object which floats around
- `fireballSpeed` is a float which indicates the floating speed
- `distance` is the distance from the boss enemy

I get that we are just updating the transforms position but I don't quite understand the `Time.time * fireballSpeed` part. I also get that `Cos` and `Sin` are returning positions for X and Y but I need to improve my math knowledge to completely wrap my head around it to be honest.

So any explanation would be great.

Comment: Does this image answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#/media/File:Circle_cos_sin.gif

Comment: It certainly helps, thanks alot! But i still cant figure out the Time.time * fireballSpeed part. What bothers me is, that the Time.time is always increasing right? How does it work that the object is flying the same circle all the time?

Comment: An interesting property of the sine and cosine functions is that they are repeating indefinitely. So no matter how large the input value gets, the output value keeps oscillating between +1 and -1.

Comment: This looks to me like a math question, rather than a game development question. You might want to [refresh your understanding of trigonometry and the unit circle](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=khan+academy+unit+circle&ia=web) first, since tons of high-quality guides about that topic have already been written. Then you can ask here if you have a game-specific question about how to apply that math to serve your particular gameplay needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the sine and cosine function is to turn an angle into X and Y coordinates. Here is an animation from Wikipedia ([source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Circle_cos_sin.gif)) which visualizes what these functions do as the input angle is incrasing:
[image: sine and cosine animation]

An interesting property of these functions is that they are repeating every 360°. The sine of 10° is 0.17364. The sine of 3600010° (1000 full rotations and then an additional 10°) is also 0.17364. No matter how large the input value gets, the output value keeps oscillating between +1 and -1.

Which means that feeding a continuously increasing timer into the sine and cosine functions is a perfectly valid method to create a continuous rotation.

Although there is one aspect you might want to keep in mind: **Floating point accuracy**. [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) is a float. The larger a floating point value gets, the less accurate does it become. This can be a problem in a situation like this where the least significant parts of the number are the most important. So when your game runs for a very long time, then this rotating animation might get a bit choppy.

One possible fix is to use double accuracy instead, which means that you use [`Time.timeAsDouble`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeAsDouble.html) instead of `Time.time` and [`System.Math`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-5.0#methods) instead of `Unity.Mathf`:

```
-Math.Cos(Time.timeAsDouble * fireballSpeed) * distance
```